# How to invoke a Biometrics device from a webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, biometrics

I need to invoke a Biometric device from a webview.

Please suggest.

Comment: The page you need right now is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There is an override method in webview.

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    //opens links in webview
    view.loadUrl(url);

    if(url.endsWith("logout")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

SO if you have an url in web, that invokes biomentric, this is how you can do that.

Or is it something else, you wanted to ask.

Comment: Thanks Manish , shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is not working above API 21